# How to bring figure legend to front?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of subplots where each one has a legend I want to be outside each subplot overlapping the neighboring subplot. The problem is that the legend is 'on top' of its own plot but below the neighboring plot. Legend does not take zorder as an argument so I am not sure how to solve the problem. This is the code I have used:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

f, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.15,wspace=0.1)

for i,j in enumerate([ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4],start=1):
    j.set_title(r'%s'%i)

ax1.plot(x, y,label='curve')
ax2.scatter(x, y)
ax3.scatter(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')
ax4.plot(x, 2 * y ** 2 - 1, color='r')

bbox=(1.3, 1.)
ax1.legend(loc=1,bbox_to_anchor=bbox)
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

[image]

Comment: if using **twinx**: see [Data being plotted over legend when using twinx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29010078/10197418)

Answer (score 6):

Legend does not take a `zorder` argument, but `axes` object does:

You can try:

```
ax2.set_zorder(-1)
```

So `ax2` goes behind ax1.

Alternatively, you can bring the `ax1` forward:

```
ax1.set_zorder(1)
```

and as your legend is an object of `ax1`, it will bring the legend (of `ax1`) on top of the second plot.

HTH