# matplotlib: Make legend appear above other subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to make a legend that can overlay all subplots in a figure. If I set its `framealpha=1.0` then it covers stuff on its subplot, but I need it to lie "on top of" the data in other subplots too. Note that I need have the red lines to pass BEHIND the legend; by 'above' I'm talking about the z dimension, not its y position.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.rand(25)
y1 = np.random.rand(25)
x2 = np.random.rand(25)
y2 = np.random.rand(25)

f, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)
axes[0].plot(x1,y1,'b-',label='data 1 blah blah blah this is a wide legend that should sit top of BOTH subplots')
axes[1].plot(x2,y2,'r-')
axes[0].axis('off')
axes[1].axis('off')

leg = axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, .8), loc=2, fontsize=8, frameon=True, framealpha = 1.0)
rect = leg.get_frame()
rect.set_facecolor([0.9,0.9,0.9])
leg.set_zorder(100)
plt.show()
```

[image]

THANKS!

Comment: related: [How to bring figure legend to front?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33150598/10197418)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, `zorder` changes the order in which different artists are drawn (see, for example, the related [demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html) from [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org)).

The problem raised by the OP of not having the legend overlaid on top of *all* of the subplots derives from the fact that `zorder` is set for the legend, which is a children of the subplot in `axes[0]`. So, changing that value affects the order only within `axes[0]`. Using the function `get_zorder` (e.g., `axes[0].get_zorder()`) allows to check the `zorder` for the different subplots, and it is possible to see that `axes[0]` and `axes[1]` have the same `zorder`. This causes the legend not to be on the foreground of the right subplot.

In order to solve the problem, as `axes[0]` is the plot with the legend, its `zorder` should be set to a higher value (e.g., `axes[0].set_zorder(100)`). 
This results in the correct display of the legend, as shown in the following figure.
Note that drawing in different orders the artists in the figure can be generalized; one useful function of `figure` is `get_children()` that returns all the artists in the figure, and thus allowing to iterate over all of them
.
[image: Resulting image with legend correctly on the foreground.]

Comment: By "above" I mean that the legend should lie over the red lines in the example. The zorder is the thing that I want to lie above the others. I've edited my question to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood at the beginning the question, and thanks for the more clear question. Now I changed the answer to reply to your specific question of having the legend on top of every subplots.