# Bring the legend to the foreground in matplotlib, only one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

How does one bring the legend to the foreground, erasing the curves that appear in the same space as the legend? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010078/matplotlib-data-being-plotted-over-legend-when-using-twinx), but this `zorder` does not work in my case. I think the reason is that I don't have subfigures, just one figure.

The code is

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(index,a1, color='red', label=r'$E_i = \pm1.93$')
ax.plot(index,a2, color='blue', label=r'$E_j = \pm1.41$')  
ax.plot(index,a3, color='green', label=r'$E_k = \pm0.51$')
plt.ylim([-0.05,1.05])
plt.xlabel(r'$x$', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel(r'$y$', fontsize=18)
plt.xticks([0,10,20], ('0', '10', '20'), fontsize=18)
ax.legend(loc=1,bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.98), fontsize=13, frameon=False).set_zorder(2)
```

Comment: Up to 20, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work either. I just checked.

Comment: Putting the frame it does shadow the background, but it doesn't completely erases it. In any case, I'm looking for a solution without frame, if it exists.

Comment: `legend(.... frameon=True, framealpha=1, edgecolor='none') `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot), specifically [Placing the legend (bbox_to_anchor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot/43439132#43439132)

Comment: Not quite. @JohanC gave the answer.