# Add a legend that covers the lines of the twinx axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, twinx

I have this python code.

1. it twinx the axis `ax` and plots some function on both axis
2. I plot the legend on `ax1`

The problem is that the legend is not covering the curves of `ax2`

It is possible to **automatically positioning** the legend on `ax` by covering the lines of `ax2`.

Note that in `fig.legend` the option `loc="best"` is not available.
And I need the automatic positioning inside the area of the plot.

Tnx

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set the x values for the sine and cosine functions
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

# Create the figure and an axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# Plot the sine and cosine functions on the axis
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), label='Cosine')

ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x+1), label='Cosine 2', color="red")
ax2.plot(x, x, label='Cosine 2', color="green")

# Add a title and labels to the axis
ax.set_title('Sine and Cosine Functions')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

# Get the line legends from the axis
lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Add a legend to the figure
ax.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0)
ax.get_legend().set_zorder(10)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

Bellow is the output of the code:

[image: The output of the code above:]

Comment: A simple solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010078/data-being-plotted-over-legend-when-using-twinx

Answer (score 2):

References:

> https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html
> https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html

The `zorder` of a `legend` is highest by default, so you don't need to modify it if you want the `legend` on the top of everything.

##### Option 1:

You can accomplish this in terms of a `Figure` object instead of an `Axes` object with `plt.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')`.

##### Option 2:

Or you can set the legend on `ax2` instead of `ax` with `ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')`. This returns the same result as in option 1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set the x values for the sine and cosine functions
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

# Create the figure and an axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

# Plot the sine and cosine functions on the axis
ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax.plot(x, np.cos(x), label='Cosine')

ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x + 1), label='Cosine 2', color="red")
ax2.plot(x, x, label='Cosine 2', color="green")

# Add a title and labels to the axis
ax.set_title('Sine and Cosine Functions')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

# Get the line legends from the axis
lines, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Add a legend to the figure
plt.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

##### Results (`loc='lower left'` and `loc='lower center'`):

[image]

[image]

##### Updated:

Reference: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx.html

With option 2 in my previous answer, I edited line 36 to `ax2.legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower right')` and line 43 to `ax22.legend(lines1 + lines22, labels1 + labels22, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')` in your newly provided code.

If you have multiple subfigures, using `Axes` objects are much more flexible.

##### It is now working correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer.

But my problem is more complex: I need to do this job in tiled subplots where every plot area is `twinx`.

By using the `plt.label` it seems to be impossible to select the plot-tile where to put the legend.

With the code below the problem is there. The lines of the twined are not covered by the legend.

Any suggestion?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Set the x values for the sine and cosine functions
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)

# Create the figure and an axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax2 = ax[0].twinx()
ax22 = ax[1].twinx()

# Plot the sine and cosine functions on the axis
ax[0].plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine 0')
ax[0].plot(x, np.cos(x), label='Cosine 0')

# Plot the sine and cosine functions on the axis
ax[1].plot(x, np.sin(x), label='Sine')
ax[1].plot(x, np.cos(x), label='Cosine')

ax2.plot(x, np.cos(x + 1), label='Cosine 2', color="red")
ax2.plot(x, x, label='Cosine B', color="green")

ax22.plot(x, np.cos(x + 2), label='Line 2', color="red")
ax22.plot(x, x, label='Cosine 2', color="green")

# Add a title and labels to the axis
ax[0].set_title('Sine and Cosine Functions')
ax[0].set_xlabel('X')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Y')

# Get the line legends from the axis
lines, labels = ax[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Add a legend to the figure
ax[0].legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower right')


lines1, labels1 = ax[1].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines22, labels22 = ax22.get_legend_handles_labels()

# Add a legend to the figure
ax[1].legend(lines1 + lines22, labels1 + labels22, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

That is controlling the z-order of the Axis and the alpha of the axis with the highest priority.

the matplotlib functions are:

`Axes.set_zorder`

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_zorder.html

&

`Patch.set_alpha`

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html

Replace the last part of the code in the third answer with the above code, and it produces the desired result.

```py
# Get the line legends from the axis
lines, labels = ax[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()


##############################################################################
############################################################################## 
# Set the z-order of axis 2 to a low "priority"
ax2.set_zorder(0)

# Set the z-order of the axis 0 to a higher priority.
# And to make visible axis 2 set the alpha of the background at 0.
ax[0].set_zorder(1)
ax[0].patch.set_alpha(0.0)
 
ax[0].legend(lines + lines2, labels + labels2, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')
##############################################################################
##############################################################################
 
lines1, labels1 = ax[1].get_legend_handles_labels()
lines22, labels22 = ax22.get_legend_handles_labels()
 
# Add a legend to the figure
ax22.legend(lines1 + lines22, labels1 + labels22, framealpha=1.0, loc='lower left')
 
# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]